# ThymeLeaf fragment (with Bootstrap) only works on index file and not other html files (Java Spring)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I have previously been using thymeleaf fragments successfully when referencing a URL bootstrap link ("https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"). I have been using th:replace for all of my files, and have had no issues getting the html fragments to my other files.

I have since tried to make the switch to BootSwatch to give my Java app a better look, and have ran into an issue. The problem is that the bootstrap only works for my index.html file, and not for my other files. Since the index file is utilizing the bootstrap design from fragments, I assume it is wired up correctly. Also, all other parts of my app work. For brevity, I'm not including all of my html files.

I am using the exact same th:replace for all my files, so I'm not sure what the issue could be.

**fragments.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:fragment="head">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title th:text = "${title}"></title>

    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/materia/bootstrap.min.css" th:href="@{css/materia/bootstrap.min.css}"/>

    <script th:src="@{webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{webjars/jquery/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>

</head>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary" th:fragment="navigation">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Store</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/cheese">List</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/cheese/add">Add</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/cheese/remove">Remove</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/cheese/account">Account</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/cheese/signup">Signup</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorate="~{fragments/main_layout}">

<head th:replace="fragments :: head"></head>
<body>

<nav th:replace="fragments :: navigation"></nav>

<h1 th:text="${title}">Add Cheeses</h1>
<p th:unless = "${cheeses} and ${cheeses.size()}">No Cheeses :(</p>

<table class="table">

    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>

    <tr th:each ="cheese : ${cheeses}">
        <td th:text ="${cheese.name}"></td>
        <td th:text ="${cheese.description}"></td>
        <td th:text ="${cheese.price}"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

**add.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorate="~{fragments/main_layout}">

<head th:replace="fragments :: head"></head>
<body>

<nav th:replace="fragments :: navigation"></nav>

<h1 th:text="${title}">Add Cheeses</h1>

<form method="post" style="max-width:600px;">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name-field">Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="name-field" type="text" name="cheeseName" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="desc-field">Description</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="desc-field" type="text" name="cheeseDescription" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="price-field">Price</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="price-field" type="text" name="cheesePrice" />
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Cheese</button>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I actually found out that Bootswatch also has a bootstrap CDN. I just replaced the local css files with a URL bootstrap link, and it worked fine.